# Page_Init vs Page_PreRender conflict with rendering LI and CSS

Tags: css, asp.net

Hi and thanks in advance.

I have an issue where I show some links at the top of page (they are not breadcrumbs) and for different circumstances I need to turn some on/off and for the page the user is on highlight that one. When I originally put the page together the call to the function that displays the links was in the Page_Init like so in the master page:

```
protected new void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetTabs(session);
}

protected void SetTabs(session)
{
    makeTab.add(session.param, session.param);
    makeTab.generate();
}

protected void add(param, param)
{
    Tabs.add(new tab() { link = param, name  = param }); 
}

protected void generate()
{
    foreach(tab t in Tabs)
    {
        liTab.Text = string.Format("<li><a href=\"{2}\">{1}</a>", t.name, t.link);
    }
}
```

The links that get created are an unordered list of items displayed inline.

And I have a separate method that is applying a style change to highlight the link that is associated with the page that the user is on that is called from the Page_Load of the page itself:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.makeTabBlue(nameOfTab);
}
```

However, in order to make hidden tabs reappear correctly, I had to move SetTabs(session) to the Page_PreRender function so that they would be called after the page was saved, when session is updated but now that I have done that the function that makes the tabs blue no longer has an effect. I've read about the page life cycle and I think that the CSS that's rendered in makeTabBlue is only effective during the Page_PreInit or Page_Init cycles but if I move the makeTabBlue to either of those then the page starts throwing additional errors that the controls can't be found which makes sense because they aren't called until PreRender. And calling it in the save function has no effect either. Where should I be calling makeTabBlue from so that it works correctly?

UPDATE:

In this particular situation, the resolution to my issue was to leave the SetTabs in the Page_Init, leave makeTabBlue in the Page_Load and I added a unique class to the LI and I am hiding, showing the links via javascript by storing values in a hidden field and checking that field when the js loads.

Answer (score 1):

The last time you can do something with the page is on the `Page_LoadComplete()` (the one before PreRender) method. Changes to the markup will still take effect if you do it here. This should allow you to run some code in your init then run stuff later on whilst still affecting the front end.

Another option would be to add a variable in the code behind:

```
protected string TabColour = "some default colour";
```

Then on the front end, do something like:

```
<div style='color:#<%= TabColour %>'></div>
```

Where the div example above is your tab.

This would allow you to set `TabColour` on the prerender event but still show the correct colour on the front end as it's evaluated in the `Rendering` event. I prefer this method as page life cycle can be tricky and this avoids being constrained by it.

Comment: Does this mean I should try moving SetTabs to Page_LoadComplete or makeTabBlue? Currently SetTabs is in PreRender so moving makeTabBlue would not work in Page_LoadComplete because its still before the PreRender.

Comment: @ElaineK - See my edit, it's probably a better solution for you.